# How to create a popup link in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

I am trying to use angular to open an popup window in my case.

I have something like

```
 <a ng-href = "window.open('{{videoLink}}')" >open a video</a>
```

It gave me 'Not found' error in browser.

However, this will open a video but it's in another tab in browser.

```
 <a ng-href = {{videoLink}}>open a video</a>
```

How do I open my video successfully in popup.

Thanks!

Comment: The code provided is not enough for me, perhaps you can prepare a better example

Comment: Indeed. you need to provide more code - preferably a Plunker/JSFiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-click` like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280302/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-my-case).

Your problem was that `ng-click` takes an AngularJS expression. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

> "If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view."

So just set a function in the `$scope` of the controller for that element and call it through `ng-click="clickHander()"`.

If this doesn't help, you need to post more code (preferably in JSFiddle or something like).